# special subgroup of real numbers

Tags: group-theory

I have a question about subgroups of the real numbers., If
$$A=\{\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n}\mid m,n\in \Bbb{N}\}$$ 
then $A$ is subgroup of $(\Bbb{R},+)$?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is false. We have that $\sqrt{2}$ belongs to $A$, as well as $\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}$, but $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}$ is an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree $\color{red}{\text{eight}}$, hence it cannot belong to $A$.

Comment: I was just about to give a similar answer, but I was working on an equation that your number satisfies of degree eight. Can you show such an equation and refer to a proof that no lower degree will work?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: It is a well-known result in algebraic number theory that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\ldots,\sqrt{p_k}):\mathbb{Q}]=2^k$. In this case we can just compute a candidate minimal polynomial for $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and check that it is a degree eight irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Very helpful...now I think it is good to learn some number theory...